# Codeigniter model database return just one line

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I am using ajax to retrieving some data from database and I have 3 lines on database and that just retrieve me 1 line of data. I try with other query and thats ok. 
'COD_DISTRITO' is a foreign key.

model Codeigniter -> that table have 3 lines and I just receive 1 line

```
function getConselhosDistrito($idDestrito) {
    $this->db->select('*');
    $this->db->from('CONCELHO');
    $this->db->where('COD_DISTRITO', $idDestrito);
    $query = $this->db->get();
    return $query;
}
```

Controller Codeigniter

```
public function getConcelhosDistrito(){
    $id = $this->input->post('iddestrito');
    $data = $this->Consulta_model->getOcorrencias()->result_array();
    echo json_encode($data);
}
```

////////////////////////

And that query works fine

```
function getOcorrencias(){
    $this->db->select('*');
    $this -> db -> from('OCORRENCIA1');
    $query = $this->db->get();
    return $query;
}
```

Comment: Provide your both table structures and both sample data. If not, then it would be hard to test and find the solution.